# Importing a kangaroo scrotum wallet to the United States

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, australia

Due to a long story, I'd like to bring an authentic Australian kangaroo nutsack wallet as a gag gift to a colleague in Seattle, Washington:

[image]

**But can I legally import this, and do I need to declare it?**  For avoidance of doubt, yes, that's an actual kangaroo scrotum, tanned and
processed into leather.

I'm aware that California has recently (Jan 1, 2016) chosen to [ban all kangaroo products](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixiZvdrvfMAhVS0WMKHccKDoIQFggtMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.news.com.au%2Ffinance%2Fbusiness%2Fretail%2Faustralia-will-continue-pushing-for-california-to-lift-its-ban-on-the-sale-and-import-of-kangaroo-products%2Fnews-story%2F3063119369e7a5a2a89870bb73097089&usg=AFQjCNF-t6m_d9cuq9b8ucdHai2I-K8lnw&sig2=z6tAAJ_6-lyjJdvWtJa3Tw&bvm=bv.122852650,d.dGo), but this is a different state and not a federal regulation.  A [search on cbp.gov](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/list/search/1/kw/Kangaroo%20Products/suggested/1) was also less than helpful.

Comment: Bring an extra for me also

Comment: @GayotFow Next round of Travel.SE schwag: sorted!

Comment: +1 for 'gag gift'. I have one of these- not really big enough to put anything of value into it (unless you're a kangaroo, of course).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Products made from the common eastern gray kangaroo and red kangaroo are generally permitted to be imported into the US, though products from threatened and endangered kangaroo species are not.

You do need to declare it to Customs. It would be helpful if the product includes documentation of what species of kangaroo it was made from, though if it was something sold as a tourist souvenir in Australia, it will likely not be something of concern.

See [this FAQ entry](https://www.fws.gov/permits/faqs/FaqIJK.html) from the Fish and Wildlife Service, shown here in relevant part:

> Do I need a permit to import, export, or re-export kangaroo hides or hide products?  The eastern gray kangaroo (Macropus giganteus) and red kangaroo (M. rufus) are not listed under CITES or the ESA.  Other species of kangaroos, rat-kangaroos, tree kangaroos, and wallabies may be listed.  Click here for a fact sheet on CITES and ESA.
>
> - To import, export, or re-export hides or hide products from the eastern gray or red kangaroo, you do not need a CITES or ESA permit from us. You should check with the Australian wildlife authorities if importing directly from Australia.
> - If you are importing kangaroo hides or products for your personal use in your accompanying baggage, you must declare the items on the Customs declaration form.

And of course I suggest not making anywhere in California your port of entry.

Comment: Why not California?

Comment: @CMaster See the question.

Comment: Flying Oz to West coast USA without entering in CA sounds like a whole new fun question.  I think you'd have to land at DFW

Comment: @PeterM Hawaiian Airlines, SYD-HNL-SEA. As a bonus, these are usually the cheapest or nearly the cheapest tickets!

Comment: I forgot about itineraries like that.  I generally have to trade off price for shorter duration in order to keep my spouse from harming me when we fly east coast USA to Oz

Comment: @PeterM Actually, I'll most likely fly Air Canada via Vancouver, SYD-YVR-SEA.

Comment: @PeterM plenty of Asian flights land in SEA or PDX. In fact I don't even remember last time I flew from Asia directly into CA.